# My App Cannot get Some User's List of Friends - PHP

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-authentication

I have a website using Facebook connect and I need to know the number of friends each of my users have.  I don't need the entire list of their friend's names but so far returning that list and counting the number in the array is how I've been doing it.  The problem is that some users who have authorized my app still are not returning that list.  It works fine for many users but not some.  I can't understand why.  My guess is that there is some privacy setting these users have set so that it cannot be viewed.  But what?  I've played with some test accounts and cannot find anything that will do this.

Here are the privledges I am asking for with PHP.

```
if ($facebook->getSession()) {
$uid = $facebook->getUser();          
$fbme = $facebook->api('/me');          
} else {          
$params = array(     
'fbconnect'=>0,
'canvas'=>1,    
'req_perms'=>'email,user_birthday,user_location,user_about_me'
);
```

Comment: This is almost certainly a permissions issue. See my answer here on a similar issue involving missing photos: http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/a/7209187/223594

Comment: I agree it is probably something to do with privacy.  I've played with those settings and in my test accounts can't do anything that stops my app from seeing the friend list.  (Unless I specifically restrict my specific app.  Which I know users are not doing).  But some users still have it where I can't see their friendlist.  I've been logging the me/permissions value to see what permissions I'm getting.  I started asking for read_friendlists permissions but still have at least one user who I see I did not get granted that permission when I view the log.  That is probably my problem.  But why?

Comment: Was there any correlation between the user who did not grant read_friendlists and not being able to read their friends (eg, is that one user the only one for whom you can't get the list of friends)? I believe the permissions request dialog now allows users to opt out of certain permissions your app requests.

Answer (score 0):

I had almost the same problem too. I had this simple application that sent virtual presents, but some of the users couldn't even see the request dialog of it, I concluded that it was the access token of some of the users, or even more deep than that, was the user's account privacy.

Seems like that's really your problem here.

Comment: So is there an account privacy setting I can change in a test user to replicate this problem?  I see a user's privacy tab but don't see any general setting that would restrict your friend list.

Comment: Sadly I don't have idea of what setting could be the one causing this problem, given that some of the accounts my app didn't work on, wasn't even close to me, I just had to re do the app.

Answer (score 0):

Following java script snippet will do it for you.

```
 var query1 = FB.Data.query('SELECT friend_count FROM user WHERE uid = me()');

  query1.wait(function(rows) {
     alert("friend count="+rows[0].friend_count);

      });
```

Comment: Ok, that may work for people that I already know it works for.  However, I want to know if there is some permission or something I can ask for so that this works for everyone.

Comment: It will work for anyone who authorizes your app with user_about_me permission. By the way what do u exactly want a list of friends or just friend count.

Comment: Yes, I simply want a friend count.  But asking for that via PHP I get nothing back for any user.  Even ones where I can get the entire friend list. I simply ask for:  $user->friend_count in the same way I'm asking for $user->birthday which works fine.  But friend_count returns nothing, so the only way I've been able to do it is get the entire friend list and then count how many there are.

Answer (score 0):

Make an HTTP post to `me/permissions` which returns a list of permissions accepted.  Ensure that it has all of your requested permissions you need for your app to operate.